# Email and Confirm email matching is giving an error in Android

Tags: android, regex, pattern-matching

i want to match the email and confirm_email if email and confirm email doesn't match then it has to give an error . When both matches then it must not display as error but what ever i enter there it is going to "Confirm Email is Not Matching" in the code below can anyone tell how to make an validation for email and confirm email checking

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String valid_email = null;
    String v5,v4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    final EditText editText4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirm_email);

    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {    
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
            Is_Valid_Email_Address(editText3);
        }
    });
    editText4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Is_Valid_Confirm_Address(editText4);
        }
    });

    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            v4 = editText3.getText().toString();
            v5 = editText4.getText().toString();  

public void Is_Valid_Confirm_Address(EditText editText4) {
    if (editText4.getText().toString() == null) {
        editText4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        valid_email = null;
    } else if (isEmailValid(editText4.getText().toString()) == false) {
        editText4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        valid_email = null;
    } else if (editText4.getText().toString() != v4) {
        editText4.setError("Confirm Email is Not Matching"); // if i enter the same address it will give this error
        valid_email = null;
    } else {
        valid_email = editText4.getText().toString();
    }

}

public void Is_Valid_Email_Address(EditText editText3) {
    if (editText3.getText().toString() == null) {
        editText3.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        valid_email = null;
    } else if (isEmailValid(editText3.getText().toString()) == false) {
        editText3.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        valid_email = null;
    } else {
        valid_email = editText3.getText().toString();
    }

}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {

    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
}
```

Comment: I assume there is a closing bracket missing after `v5 = editText4.getText().toString();  ` ?

Comment: Your issue is because you are not using .equals - see Simple Plan's response below.

Comment: DO NOT use != == operators to comparing String values, you should use .equals(String) method

Comment: i will check it out Bro @CompuChip

Comment: Thanks bro if any issues i will ask in SO @JamieB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
 if (editText3.getText().toString().equals(editText4.getText().toString())) {

    editText4.setError("Invalid Email Address");

 }else{

  editText4.setError("Email Address Match!!!!");
  }
```

Used `.equals()` method for `String` comparison

Comment: i am getting error near editText4 when i checked it it automatically creates an edittext3 keyword inside this method and intialises to null if i replace it with v4 the app crashes

Comment: 'public void Is_Valid_Confirm_Address(EditText editText4) {
 EditText editText3 = null;
 if (editText4.getText().toString() == null) {
  editText4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
  valid_email = null;
 } else if (isEmailValid(editText4.getText().toString()) == false) {
  editText4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
  valid_email = null;
 } else if (editText4.getText().toString().equals(editText3.getText().toString())) {
  editText4.setError("Confirm Email is Not Matching");
  valid_email = null;
 } else {
  valid_email = editText4.getText().toString();
 }'

Comment: bro i am not getting which line i have to replace can u tell little in depth or just share the code snippet i will get the output

Comment: @SandeepV you got it or i'll explain more.

Comment: no no got it i will try and let u know bro @Simple Plan

Comment: one more question bro can i add send button enable and disable thing in this code in the sense if i get error then disable send button and error is not present then enable send button @Simple Plan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52554/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-sandeep-v)

Answer (score 0):

And you should `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing Strings